# Terms of an equation in different order

Tags: equation, maxima

I'm using wxMaxima 15.08.1 (win 10) and when I input this equation

```
/* [wxMaxima: input   start ] */a*x+b*y+c*z=0;
```

I get this:

```
/* [wxMaxima: input   end   ] */cz+by+ax=0
```

Why does it change the term's position of the expression? It seems like in descending order somehow.

Then, if I type another equation giving all coefficients the same unknown, maxima outputs it just right.

```
/* [wxMaxima: input   start ] */a*x^2+b*x+c=0;

/* [wxMaxima: input   end   ] */ax^2+bx+x=0
```

Comment: well, the whole point is that there's no right or wrong here

Comment: Sure thing, I'm just wondering if there is any reason behind this.

Comment: maxima reorders things just as it likes to handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maxima has its own idea of the canonical ordering of terms in "+" and "*" expressions. The canonical ordering is expressed by the function `ordergreatp` (equivalently `orderlessp`) which tells if one term comes after (respectively, before) another term. If you apply `sort` to a list of terms, they are sorted, by default, according to the canonical order.

By default, "+" terms are displayed in reverse order (reverse of the canonical order). When the global variable `powerdisp` is `true`, "+" terms are displayed in the canonical order. You can decide whether one order or the other works better for you.

```
(%i2) powerdisp;
(%o2)                         false
(%i3) a*x + b*y + c*z;
(%o3)                    c z + b y + a x
(%i4) a*x^2 + b*x + c;
                            2
(%o4)                    a x  + b x + c

(%i7) powerdisp : true $
(%i8) a*x + b*y + c*z;
(%o8)                    a x + b y + c z
(%i9) a*x^2 + b*x + c;
                                      2
(%o9)                    c + b x + a x
```